# How to update a primary key column which should reflect in foreign key column?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables `emp_details` and `dep_details`.

In `emp_details` the fields are (`empid`, `empname`, `empsal`, `deptId(f.key)`) and in `dept_details` fields are (`deptID(P.key)`, `deptname`).

If I update the `empname`, `empsal` and `deptname` from `empdetails` and `deptdetails`, the primary key column and foreign key column `deptID` must get updated simultaneously.

Below is the Stored Procedure that I tried:

```
alter proc UpdateEmployeeDetail(@eid int ,@ename varchar(30),@esal float, @deptid varchar(30),@deptname varchar(30))
as 
begin
update e set e.ename=@ename, e.esal=@esal, e.deptid=@deptid from
 EmployeeDetails e where  e.eid=@eid
 update d set d.deptid=@deptid, d.deptname=@deptname from  DepartmentDetails d  , EmployeeDetails e
 where e.deptid=d.deptid and d.deptid=@deptid
end 
go'
```

Comment: Why would you mix in one procedure the updating of a department (deptid and deptname) with the updating of one employee (empid, empname, empsal)? I would have these as 2 different procedures.

Comment: Off course the dept-update procedure would have to update also all the related `emp.deptid` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just change constraint between tables (ON UPDATE CASCADE)..:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_SomeFK FOREIGN KEY
    (
        SomeID
    ) REFERENCES dbo.OtherTable
    (
        SomeId
    ) ON UPDATE CASCADE 
     ON DELETE NO ACTION
```